# R: Using dplyr group_by with ggplot2 and changing title per group

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have the following example dataframe `df_summarised` which in reality will have more years and Isotope data.

```
structure(list(Isotope = c("TC99M", "TC99M", "TC99M", "TC99M", 
"TC99M", "TC99M", "TC99M", "TC99M", "TL201", "TL201", "TL201", 
"TL201", "TL201", "TL201", "TL201", "TL201"), month = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L), .Label = c("Jan", 
"Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", 
"Nov", "Dec"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), year = c(2021, 
2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
2021, 2021, 2021, 2021), TotalMonthlyExcretion = c(17705.648, 
20717.156, 27443.508, 19528.556, 22711.792, 20083.524, 17791.076, 
9223.8, 163.695, 738.51, 1055.775, 906.438, 482.082, 741.984, 
605.211, 265.641), MonthlyLimits_MBq = c(80000, 80000, 80000, 
80000, 80000, 80000, 80000, 80000, 5600, 5600, 5600, 5600, 5600, 
5600, 5600, 5600)), .Names = c("Isotope", "month", "year", "TotalMonthlyExcretion", 
"MonthlyLimits_MBq"), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to create an individual plot for each isotope, year combination and save as a separate png file. For each isotope/year pairing, I want to change the title to reflect the pairing. I have tried the following:

```
ActivityPlots <- df_summarised %>%
    group_by(Isotope,year) %>%
    do(
       plots = ggplot(data=., aes(x=month,y=TotalMonthlyExcretion)) +
       geom_bar(stat="identity", width = .5, fill="tomato3") +
       labs(title = paste("Liquid Radioactive Waste. Year: ", df_summarised$year," Isotope: ", df_summarised$Isotope),
           x = "Month",
           y = "Total Monthly Excretion (MBq)",
           caption = paste("Year: ",df_summarised$year)
           ) +
       theme_bw() +
       theme(
            plot.title = element_text(color="black", size=14, face="bold.italic"),
            axis.title.x = element_text(size=14, face="bold"),
            axis.title.y = element_text(size=14, face="bold"))
       )
```

However, the plot title for each plot is the same: 'Liquid Radioactive Waste. Year 2021 Isotope TC99M'. I'm assuming this is picking up the values from the first entry of the data frame.

What is the best way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `split` and `map`. To save the plots as png you can include  `ggsave`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df_summarised %>%
  group_split(Isotope,year) %>%
  map(~{
    plots = ggplot(data=.x, aes(x=month,y=TotalMonthlyExcretion)) +
      geom_bar(stat="identity", width = .5, fill="tomato3") +
      labs(title = paste("Liquid Radioactive Waste. Year: ", .x$year[1]," Isotope: ", .x$Isotope[1]),
           x = "Month",
           y = "Total Monthly Excretion (MBq)",
           caption = paste("Year: ",.x$year[1])
      ) +
      theme_bw() +
      theme(
        plot.title = element_text(color="black", size=14, face="bold.italic"),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size=14, face="bold"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size=14, face="bold"))
    
    ggsave(sprintf('plots%s_%s.png', .x$Isotope[1], .x$year[1]), plots)
  })
```

Comment: Thanks. Which library does the  `group_split` function come from? I have tidyverse library loaded but receive the error message 'Could not find function "group_split"

Comment: `group_split` is part of `dplyr` which should be loaded with `tidyverse`. What version is your `dplyr` package? It has been a while since `group_split` was introduced. I think it was included in 0.8.0. I am using `dplyr` 1.0.7 now.

Comment: Ah that will be the issue. I'm on `dplyr` 0.7.4. Not used R in quite a while. Cheers